# Unable to connect networkshares through VPN (RRAS server only)

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, network-share, pptp, rras

I have a Windows Server 2008 SP2 with these Roles installed:

1. File server
2. Network Policy and Access Server / Routing and Remote Access
3. Network Policy and Access Server / NPS

The VPN connection is connecting, but it is not possible to share a Network folder situated on this server. Shares on other servers in the same network work as expected.

Trying to map a network share through Windows Explorer gives the following error:

```
The mapped network drive could not be created because the following error has occurred:
The specified network name is no longer available.
```

`net view \\rras-server` gives the following error, while `net view \\other-servers` works and shows the shared folders available.

```
Error 53: The network path was not found.
```

I tried to troubleshot and found these indications:

- Ping works on server name and IP address
- Nslookup shows that DNS lookup is working as it should
- Disabling the firewall on the server does not help
- The same problem occurs with Windows XP and Windows 7

Where could be the problem ?

---

The following behavior shows when the client computer is on the local network, but VPN is connected (The advanced setting `Use default gateway on remote network` is not checked):

In Windows Exporer, the network share shows with a red cross, and when I click on it, one of the following errors occurs:

```
An error has occurred while connecting [drive letter]: to [share name]
The parameter is incorrect

An error has occurred while connecting [drive letter]: to [share name]
The specified network name is no longer available
```

On the other hand, when I open Eplorer with the VPN disconnected, and then connect the VPN, the navigation in the network share continues to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution (I know this is not really an acceptable answer):

I installed the RRAS role on an other server that does not have file shares. Since then everything is OK.